# Appengine Search API: Exclude one document field from search

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

In the search document I have two fields which have value as Yes or No.

field1 - have value as Yes or No
field2 - have value as Yes or No

from function foo(), I want to search a document which have value as "no" and it should not search in field1.

How to archive this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just say "no", you'll search all fields in the document.  However, if you prefix your term with a field name like "field2:no" you will only search the values of that field.

Comment: I want to search "no" in all the fields except field1.